# how to make rsync to log deleted files

Tags: rsync

I'm using rsnapshot (which use rsync) to backup files from my web server to local Linux box (Synology)

Files, deleted on the web server are deleted on the Linux box, as expected.
The problem, that info about deleted files are not logged.
How can I add list of deleted files to the rsync log?

Here are rsync parameters in the rsnapshot.conf:

```
rsync_short_args -av
rsync_long_args --out-format="%t %f %b" --delete --delete-excluded \
    --log-file=/volume1/web/logs/rsn_sync.log --copy-links
```

So this results in following command:

```
/usr/syno/bin/rsync -av --out-format="%t %i %f %b" --delete --delete-excluded \

    --log-file=/volume1/web/logs/rsn_sync.log --copy-links \
    --exclude-from=/volume1/web/BK/exclude.txt --rsh=/usr/syno/bin/ssh \
    --link-dest=/volume1/web/BK2/weekly.1/slavikF/ \
    root@slavikf.com:/var/www/ /volume1/web/BK2/weekly.0/slavikF/
```

Comment: Do you get something in the output when you run the command about the deleted files? If that is the case, why you don't just redirect the output to a file?

Comment: After many trials, I found:

- flag "--itemize-changes" doesn't affect anything. There are no info about deleted files IN THE LOG. Seems to be the bug of rsync. I have version 3.09

- But information about deleted files is present in the console output (regardless of --itemize-changes).

- I can't get console output, when using rsync from rsnapshot.

- But I can use rsnapshot diff, which does, what I need to do.

Comment: You could use `luckyBackup` which is a GUI tool for rsync. It not only keeps logs but also can save the old deleted data as **versions**.

Comment: Any update on this issue? It is still not showing the delete folders/files in the log

Comment: @jlanza I've answered an old question you commented on. If you are still interested, please check it out!

Comment: I also believe this is a rsync bug, which has been there for more than 10 yrs :(  https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2013-October/028768.html

Answer (score 3):

```
-i, --itemize-changes      output a change-summary for all updates
Also:  -v, --verbose              increase verbosity
```

Comment: Note: if you use `--link-dest`, deleted files will not be listed. This is true for all the answers to this question.

https://rsync.samba.narkive.com/9lakR0U3/

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but here's the answer:

When used on a single system, rsync spins up two processes: once which is considered "local" (and sends data from the source directory) and once which is "remote" (which receives the data).

The deletions are handled on the remote side, not the local side.

The default log is created by the "local" process and doesn't show the deleted file:

```
$ rsync -a --delete-during --log-file=~/rsynclog.log src/ dest
$ cat ~/rsynclog.log
2021/05/05 23:51:09 [4244] building file list
2021/05/05 23:51:09 [4244] .d..t...... {directory}
```

But, you can cause the "remote" side to create the log. Then the deletion shows up!

```
$ rsync -a --delete-during --remote-option=--log-file=~/rsynclog.log src/ dest
$ cat ~/rsynclog.log
2021/05/05 23:39:18 [31138] receiving file list
2021/05/05 23:39:18 [31138] *deleting   {directory}/{filename}
2021/05/05 23:39:18 [31138] .d..t...... {directory}
```

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) says `--log-file-format` use `%i %n%L` by default.

You can use `%o` here. The [documentation](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.html) says:

> %o the operation, which is "send", "recv", or "del." (the latter
> includes the trailing period)

So, what you are basically looking for is:

```
--log-file-format='%i %n%L %o'
```

Comment: Did you check that using the suggested option outputs deleted files to the log? 
I am after the same target as in the OP, and I don't see this works.
Please confirm.

Comment: I was actually not getting *any* files in the log, since I was using `--dry-run`. This behaviour is described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225849/why-does-rsync-log-file-not-contain-updates-to-regular-files-when-dry-run

Comment: I use `--info=PROGRESS2,BACKUP,DEL --backup-dir=$(date +"%d-%m-%y_%I-%M-%S%P").bak --log-file-format='%t %f %o %M'` and it created a log entry like `2022/01/25 02:39:31 [13251] backed up WDPurple6TB/_Database/_Database/file.txt`

Comment: For the given format the log entry looks like `2022/01/25 02:48:51 [14366] *deleting   WDPurple6TB/_BusinessIT/text.txt del.`

Comment: Even with `--dry-run`?

Comment: `--dry-run` is supposed to not make any changes.